# Disallow to add new attributes to a class instance

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have such code

```
class Toy():

  def __init__(self, color, age):
      self.color = color
      self.age = age
      self.my_dict = {
        'name':'Yoyo',
        'has_pets': False,
    }

  def __setattr__(self, key, value):
     if key == 'color' or key == 'age' or key == 'my_dict': # want to make like this 'self.__dict__.keys()' 
         object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
     else:
         print('Wrong value')
```

Main idea is to disallow users to add new custom attributes to a class.
Is there is way to tell `__setattr__` not to check keys if it called from `__init__`?
If so then I could use `self.__dict__.keys()` in `__setattr__` and don't check every key by name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `__slots__` class attribute:

```
class Toy:

    __slots__ = ('color', 'age', 'my_dict')

    def __init__(self, color, age):
        self.color = color
        self.age = age
        self.my_dict = {
            'name':'Yoyo',
            'has_pets': False,
        }
```

Any attempt to assign to an attribute other than `color`, `age`, or `my_dict` will result in an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't found better than this

```
class Toy:

    _keys = ["color", "age", "my_dict"]

    def __init__(self, color, age):
      self.color = color
      self.age = age
      self.my_dict = {
        'name':'Yoyo',
        'has_pets': False,
        }

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self._keys:
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
        else:
            print('Wrong value')
```